# Bash string replace on command result

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a simple bash script which is getting the load average using uptime and awk, for example

```
LOAD_5M=$(uptime | awk -F'load averages:' '{ print $2}' | awk '{print $2}')
```

However this includes a ',' at the end of the load average

e.g.

```
0.51,
```

So I have then replaced the comma with a string replace like so:

```
LOAD_5M=${LOAD_5M/,/}
```

I'm not an awk or bash wizzkid so while this gives me the result I want, I am wondering if there is a succinct way of writing this, either by:

- Using awk to get the load average without the comma, or
- Stripping the comma in a single line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in same awk command:

```
uptime | awk -F 'load averages?: *' '{split($2, a, ",? "); print a[2]}'
1.32
```

Comment: I noticed some OS include a comma between each average and some don't, this doesn't work if its not there but if i change the split to `split($2,a,",? ")` i think its looking good.

Comment: Yes I tested on OSX and found comma here. Otherwise yes `split($2,a,",? ")` would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

The 5 min load is available in `/proc/loadavg`. You can simply use `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f2  /proc/loadavg
```

With `awk` you can issue:

```
awk '{print $2}' /proc/loadavg
```

---

If you are not working on Linux the file `/proc/loadavg` will not being present. In this case I would suggest to use `sed`, like this:

```
uptime | sed 's/.*, \(.*\),.*,.*/\1/'
```

Comment: I liked this until I tried it on a Mac and got `cut: /proc/loadavg: No such file or directory` so think uptime is a bit more cross platform.

Comment: Same here I also tried it on Mac and it didn't work. Probably it is Linux only trick

Comment: @murdoch Another reason to use Linux. ;)

Comment: @murdoch Btw, you might use `sed`: `uptime | sed 's/.*, \(.*\),.*,.*/\1/'` on Mac OS (or BSD) ... Will add this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
uptime | awk -F'load average:' '{ print $2}' | awk -F, '{print $2}'
0.38
```

(My uptime output has 'load average:' singular)

Answer (score 0):

The load average numbers are always the last 3 fields in the 'uptime' output so:

```
IFS=' ,' read -a uptime_fields <<<"$(uptime)"
LOAD_5M=${uptime_fields[@]: -2:1}
```